# Is it possible to prevent the time field to expect seconds in Laravel Backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm working with Laravel Backpack and for a specific model I want the user to be able to add a "start time" using the `time` field type. I want the user to enter this format: `hh:mm`.

While creating the entity it works fine. But in the edit mode the value of the input field has this format: `hh:mm:ss`

The field is declared like this:

```
[
    'name'  => 'start_time',
    'label' => "Beginn",
    'type'  => 'time'
],
```

The corresponding field in the DB looks like this:

```
$table->time('start_time')->nullable();
```

When the model is created this works as expected what means, that I can enter the time in `hh:mm` format. For example I enter "14:00".

After saving the model, in the DB I have the value stored as `14:00:00`.

Now, when I go to the edit view the value in the corresponding time input field is also `14:00:00`.

I assume this is because in the DB the value is stored including the seconds.

Is it possible to store a time in the DB without the seconds? So just in the format `hh:mm`?

For more details I have some screenshots that show what I meant:

1. On creation
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iG48.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgAS6.png)
2. The value in DB after saving
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIyqh.png)
3. The input after loading the edit view
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTlde.png)

Comment: Have you checked here? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting For solution you can define a cast in your model: `'start_time' => 'date:hh:mm'`

Comment: @cengsemihsahin I tried your approach. After adding that type cast the input field is empty in the edit mode :/ The value stored in the DB remains the same.

Comment: You want to pass partial time to a mysql time field? Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @RGServers Yeah...this might be it. Basically, I think if I can store the time as hh:mm in the db, without the seconds, this might be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it work by defining the `step` attribute in the field https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#using_the_step_attribute

Cheers